# Clear cache for just one site (Brave or Chrome or Opera browsers)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, opera, devtools, brave

While developing, I often need to clear cache data - but just wish to do so for one site.

I don't see any such option under History -> Clear browsing data

Answer (score 10):

For Brave browser, but information would also apply to any Chromium browser (Chrome, Brave, Opera, et al)

1. When viewing website in browser
2. Right click on page
3. Inspect (to open DevTools)
4. **Application** tab
5. Left side panel at very top, under Application section...
6. Click **Storage** *(formerly "Clear Storage")*
7. In right panel, click button <kbd>**Clear site data**</kbd>

Reference:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/cache/?utm_source=devtools